# How to use Rails Action Controller Nested Params to Permit a Specific Attributes Hash

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hash, strong-parameters, actioncontroller

There are a lot of questions about Nested Parameters, but I can't seem to find one that addresses my specific, simple situation.

I'm trying to permit a nested hash that is NOT an array. I expected this to work:

```
params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, style: {:font, :color})
```

But it resulted in a syntax error.

This, however, worked:

```
params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, style: [:font, :color])
```

But my issue with this, it it seems to permit `style` values that are arrays of items with attributes :font and :color. I only want to permit a single hash with those 2 attributes.

I've tried other variations, but I keep getting syntax errors. I'd appreciate any help with this.

Context: Rails 4.1.7, Ruby 2.0.0 (It's on my todo list to upgrade!), not using ActiveRecord.

Answer (score 10):

The problem is that, as your error states, you have a syntax error. This is because `{:font, :color}` is not valid Ruby. You're attempting to mix the hash syntax, `{ key: value }`, with the array syntax, `[:one, :two]`. What you're likely wanting to do is,

```
# Accept params: { book: { style: { font: value, color: value } } }
params.require(:book).permit(style: [:font, :color])
```

or,

```
# Accept params: { book: { style: [{ font: value, color: value }] } }
params.require(:book).permit(style: [[:font, :color]])
```

The fact that you're using an array of keys to accept a hash (not an array) is just how `strong_parameters` works. To accept an array, you would actually just do something like this,

```
# Accept params: { book: { style: [:font, :color] } }
params.require(:book).permit(style: [])
```

Hopefully that clarifies the issue.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like it might need to be:

```
params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, style: [{:font, :color]})
```

based on this example from the [Rails API Guide](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Parameters.html#method-i-permit)

```
   pets: [{
      name: 'Purplish',
      category: 'dogs'
    }]
```

Edit, I certainly could be wrong, but following the [rules quoted here](http://patshaughnessy.net/2014/6/16/a-rule-of-thumb-for-strong-parameters):

> TL;DR: Use this rule of thumb when trying to figure out how to
>   whitelist nested attributes: To Permit a Hash, Pass an Array To Permit
>   an Array, Pass a Hash

Comment: Is that from the pets example? I think that that is for an _array_ of pets, while I only want one pet with some attributes.

Comment: I think you're right about that rule of thumb. Scroll down in that API guide that you linked to and you see this... 
`params.require(:person).permit(contact: [ :email, :phone ])
# => {"contact"=>{"email"=>"none@test.com", "phone"=>"555-1234"}}`

Comment: When I try this out in a controller spec, the thing that I don't like is that both of the following are permitted...
1) contact: {email: "", phone: ""} <-- this is what I want to permit as it assigns the hash `{email: "", phone: ""}` to the contact attribute.
2) contact: [{email: "1", phone: "1"}, {email: "2", phone: "2"}] <-- only the last email/phone gets passed in, but it assigns the array `[{email: "2", phone: "2"}]` to the contact attribute. I don't like this; I want the contact attribute to only be assigned a hash, not an array.

Comment: I wonder if you could get it to do exactly what you want by calling it `params.permit` multiple times or passing in a separate hash like the examples used in the strong_parameters github page? 
https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters#require-multiple-parameters

Answer (score 0):

I think it should work if you wrap `style` in curly braces, i.e.:

```
params.require(:book).permit(:title, :description, { style: [:font, :color] })
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that doesn't work. I get a syntax error...
    `SyntaxError (.../books_controller.rb:333: syntax error, unexpected ',', expecting =>
...le, {style: {:font, :color}})
...`

In my test.log file, the ^ caret is pointing to the comma after `:font` as the source of the problem.

Comment: It's important to remark what @ezekg mentions: `{:font, :color}` is not valid ruby. In general terms, if you want an array of symbols, do `[:font, :color]`. If you would want a key-value hash, stick to the curly braces but do `{ :key => :value }` instead of the comma in the middle (the source of @readyornot syntax error). Or, even better, the modern syntax version `{ key: :value }` which in practice is the same.

Comment: @GabrielOsorio: you're totally right. I've fixed my answer.