# Rails 5.1 API - how to permit params for nested JSON object's attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, parameters

There are at least 10 questions on this topic but none of them answer this particular issue. Many of the questions relate to Rails forms like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32529757/how-can-i-get-strong-parameters-to-permit-nested-fields-for-attributes), which I don't have, or to json structures that are more complicated, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18436741/rails-4-strong-parameters-nested-objects?noredirect=1&lq=1) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29707624/how-to-use-rails-action-controller-nested-params-to-permit-a-specific-attributes).

---

**EDIT regarding the accepted answer and why this is not an exact duplicate**

The linked question in the answer from @CarlosRoque initially looks to be the same problem but *it only solves the Rails side of this particular issue.*

If you read all the comments you will see multiple attempts at changing the `template_params` method were made to RENAME or REPLACE the nested attribute "template_items" with "template_items_attributes". This is necessary because Rails `accepts_nested_attributes_for` requires "_attributes" to be appended to the name, otherwise it cannot see it.

If you examine the monkey patch code in that answer to fix wrap_parameters so that it works for nested attributes, you still have the problem that it won't actually find "template_items" (the nested object) because it does not have the suffix "_attributes".

Therefore to fully solve this the client also had to be modified to send the nested object as "template_items_attributes". For JS clients this can be done by implementing a toJSON() method on the object to modify it during serialization (example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46858650/angular2-4-what-is-the-correct-way-to-add-a-tojson-function-to-a-typescript-cl/46862365#46862365)). But be aware that when you deserialize the JSON, you will need to manually create an instance of that object for toJSON() to work (explained why [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863066/angular4-why-does-custom-tojson-only-get-called-on-new-objects)).

---

I have a simple has_many / belongs_to:

Models:

```
class Template < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :template_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :template_items, allow_destroy: true
end


class TemplateItem < ApplicationRecord  
  belongs_to :template
  validates_presence_of :template

  enum item_type: {item: 0, heading: 1} 
end
```

The json sent from the client looks like this:

```
{
  "id": "55e27eb7-1151-439d-87b7-2eba07f3e1f7",
  "account_id": "a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9",
  "name": "Test",
  "info": "INFO1234",
  "title": "TITLE1",
  "template_items": [
    {
      "is_completed": false,
      "item_type": "item"
    },
    {
      "is_completed": false,
      "item_type": "heading"
    }
  ]
}
```

Sometimes there will be an `:id` and a `:content` attribute in each template_item (eg. after they have been created and user starts editing them).

The `template_params` method of the `templates_controller` looks like this:

```
   params.require(:template).permit(
      :id, :account_id, :name, :title, :info, 
      template_items: [:id, :is_completed, :content, :item_type]
  )
```

If this was a Rails form then that line would be:

```
   params.require(:template).permit(
      :id, :account_id, :name, :title, :info, 
      template_items_attributes: [:id, :is_completed, :content, :item_type]
  )
```

for saving the nested children objects as part of the parent template update action.

I tried changing the nested param name:

```
def template_params
  params.require(:template).permit(:id, :account_id, :name, :title, :info, template_items: [:id, :is_completed, :content, :item_type])
  params[:template_items_attributes] = params.delete(:template_items) if params[:template_items]
  Rails.logger.info params
end
```

and I can see they are still not permitted:

```
{  
      "template"   =><ActionController::Parameters   {  
      "id"      =>"55e27eb7-1151-439d-87b7-2eba07f3e1f7",
      "account_id"      =>"a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9",
      "name"      =>"Test",
      "info"      =>"INFO1234",
      "title"      =>"TITLE1",
   }   permitted:false   >,
   "template_items_attributes"   =>   [  
      <ActionController::Parameters      {  
         "is_completed"         =>false,
         "item_type"         =>"item"
      }      permitted:false      >,
      <ActionController::Parameters      {  
         "is_completed"         =>false,
         "item_type"         =>"item"
      }      permitted:false      >
   ]
}
```

I also tried merging:

```
template_params.merge! ({template_items_attributes:
params[:template_items]}) if params[:template_items].present?
```

Same problem.

So how can I ensure they are permitted and included in template_params WITHOUT just doing .permit! (ie. I don't want to permit everything blindly)?

The controller update method:

```
def update
    Rails.logger.info "*******HERE*******"
    Rails.logger.info template_params
    @template.template_items = template_params[:template_items_attributes]

    if @template.update(template_params)
      render json: @template
    else
      render json: ErrorSerializer.serialize(@template.errors), status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

**UDPATE**

If I send from the client "template_items_attributes" instead of "template_items" inside the parameters to Rails, and then do the recommended template_params like this:

```
    def template_params
      params.require(:template).permit(:id, :account_id, :name, :title, :info, template_items_attributes: [:id, :is_completed, :content, :item_type])
    end
```

it still does not create new children for the template!

With this in place, I output the parameters before and afterwards, like this:

```
def update
    Rails.logger.info params
    Rails.logger.info "*******HERE*******"    
    Rails.logger.info template_params

    if @template.update(template_params)
      render json: @template
    else
      render json: ErrorSerializer.serialize(@template.errors), status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end
```

And here is the log from this scenario - Rails is STILL completely ignoring the embedded array. Notice that params, just before HERE, shows permitted: false and then afterwards template_params no longer contains the children "template_items_attributes" and is marked permitted:true.

```
I, [2017-10-20T21:52:39.886104 #28142]  INFO -- : Processing by Api::TemplatesController#update as JSON
I, [2017-10-20T21:52:39.886254 #28142]  INFO -- :   Parameters: {"id"=>"55e27eb7-1151-439d-87b7-2eba07f3e1f7", "account_id"=>"a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9", "name"=>"Test", "info"=>"INFO12345", "title"=>"TITLE1", "created_at"=>"2017-10-14T19:30:41.450Z", "updated_at"=>"2017-10-20T17:48:24.909Z", "template_items_attributes"=>[{"is_completed"=>false, "item_type"=>"item"}], "template"=>{"id"=>"55e27eb7-1151-439d-87b7-2eba07f3e1f7", "account_id"=>"a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9", "name"=>"Test", "info"=>"INFO12345", "title"=>"TITLE1", "created_at"=>"2017-10-14T19:30:41.450Z", "updated_at"=>"2017-10-20T17:48:24.909Z"}}
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:39.903011 #28142] DEBUG -- :   User Load (7.7ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."uid" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["uid", "rmcsharry+owner@gmail.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.072148 #28142] DEBUG -- :   Template Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "templates".* FROM "templates" WHERE "templates"."id" = $1 ORDER BY name ASC LIMIT $2  [["id", "55e27eb7-1151-439d-87b7-2eba07f3e1f7"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
I, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.083727 #28142]  INFO -- : <ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"55e27eb7-1151-439d-87b7-2eba07f3e1f7", "account_id"=>"a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9", "name"=>"Test", "info"=>"INFO12345", "title"=>"TITLE1", "created_at"=>"2017-10-14T19:30:41.450Z", "updated_at"=>"2017-10-20T17:48:24.909Z", "template_items_attributes"=>[{"is_completed"=>false, "item_type"=>"item"}], "controller"=>"api/templates", "action"=>"update", "template"=>{"id"=>"55e27eb7-1151-439d-87b7-2eba07f3e1f7", "account_id"=>"a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9", "name"=>"Test", "info"=>"INFO12345", "title"=>"TITLE1", "created_at"=>"2017-10-14T19:30:41.450Z", "updated_at"=>"2017-10-20T17:48:24.909Z"}} permitted: false>
I, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.083870 #28142]  INFO -- : *******HERE*******
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.084550 #28142] DEBUG -- : Unpermitted parameters: :created_at, :updated_at
I, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.084607 #28142]  INFO -- : <ActionController::Parameters {"id"=>"55e27eb7-1151-439d-87b7-2eba07f3e1f7", "account_id"=>"a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9", "name"=>"Test", "title"=>"TITLE1", "info"=>"INFO12345"} permitted: true>
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.084923 #28142] DEBUG -- : Unpermitted parameters: :created_at, :updated_at
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.085375 #28142] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.114015 #28142] DEBUG -- :   Account Load (1.2ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.131895 #28142] DEBUG -- :   Template Exists (0.8ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "templates" WHERE "templates"."name" = $1 AND ("templates"."id" != $2) AND "templates"."account_id" = 'a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9' LIMIT $3  [["name", "Test"], ["id", "55e27eb7-1151-439d-87b7-2eba07f3e1f7"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.133754 #28142] DEBUG -- :    (0.3ms)  COMMIT
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.137763 #28142] DEBUG -- :   CACHE Account Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.138714 #28142] DEBUG -- :    (0.2ms)  BEGIN
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.141293 #28142] DEBUG -- :   User Load (1.3ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2 FOR UPDATE  [["id", "88de3be9-6d18-4687-ab80-d50f78638ca9"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.235163 #28142] DEBUG -- :   Account Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "accounts".* FROM "accounts" WHERE "accounts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["id", "a61151b8-deed-4efa-8cad-da1b143196c9"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.240997 #28142] DEBUG -- :   SQL (1.4ms)  UPDATE "users" SET "tokens" = $1, "updated_at" = $2 WHERE "users"."id" = $3  [["tokens", "{\"ryyymFZ7fpH50rMKArjZ2Q\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$4jkgRe4LBPxJ8fQUOKCSausUi7DbIUD0bE.7ZRoOuTHrRuX6CaWOe\",\"expiry\":1509293414,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$cpI.mz81JFjQT0J9acCCl.NdrEatI5l17GtrwrAfwyhyN3xRExcaC\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-10-15T17:10:16.996+02:00\"},\"Y2y0maUT5WYSfH6VZeORag\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$8KERiIwlc3rX.Mdu.CW6wOMLDbVyB2PFCaBIlw7/LUxC3ITpYTISW\",\"expiry\":1509293475,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$r6Xw6798T1P7UZlTbEaXoeBCl9oK2fMs72ppAtars8Ai/kaE6nE66\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-10-15T17:11:18.066+02:00\"},\"9Cy48CPVj3WhFkEBPUZQ1Q\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$Qy4JOD8.jIcPhf93MqFCIelnVaA/ssE31w5DlL8MShDuMROsLSNuS\",\"expiry\":1509293942,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$e6sxklrHRRD1C15Ix/MqQOfACuCMznmzUjF296cpO1ypWVvJ.JFJK\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-10-15T17:19:05.200+02:00\"},\"O5iufW0Gacqs9sIfJ9705w\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$EkDf7.y3lY9D36lAwNHBGuct97M6/HGDvnrUsD72c8zCsfVd8y9c2\",\"expiry\":1509482450,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$S0kHEvKxom2Qgdy0r.q0aeTSlSBFkqU4XZeY91n3RkkYkQykmmGVi\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-10-17T21:40:50.300+02:00\"},\"ETOadoEtoxcz6rR6Ced_dA\":{\"token\":\"$2a$10$8t01bWv/PsVojs3cazuSg..FWa9SZwq1/PUDfuN1S4yBxnMFv2zre\",\"expiry\":1509742360,\"last_token\":\"$2a$10$hveuajISXDOjHLm9EkVzvOd3pwKkqE1rQnIFBoojf0vgMLXV2EvVe\",\"updated_at\":\"2017-10-20T21:52:40.233+02:00\"}}"], ["updated_at", "2017-10-20 19:52:40.236607"], ["id", "88de3be9-6d18-4687-ab80-d50f78638ca9"]]
D, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.243960 #28142] DEBUG -- :    (1.3ms)  COMMIT
I, [2017-10-20T21:52:40.244504 #28142]  INFO -- : Completed 200 OK in 358ms (Views: 1.0ms | ActiveRecord: 37.7ms)
```

Comment: Can you also post the controller action you have?

Comment: Thanks for adding the controller. Its seems the problem could be the fact that you don't have `optional:true`. Rails 5 forces the parent to be required.  `belongs_to : template, optional: true` . When you try this, I would also recommend using the snippet  you have under **If this was a Rails form then that line would be** when defining Strong Params. See if those edits let you save the model correctly.

Comment: The parent always exists - this is not the create action. In the create action you can only create a parent template, not children items. But in the update action you can update both the parent and its children. I will try it though as I'm getting pretty crazy, tried a million things in the past 4 hours.

Comment: Also,  you "should not" need the line `@template.template_items = template_params[:template_items_attributes]` in your actions. Part of what rails does when you define accepts nested attributes for. `@template.update(template_params)` should also read the nested attributes and update accordingly. Take a look at this blog: http://devopsdiarist.uk/rails-5-nested-attributes/ shows a very simple example but with your exact scenario.

Comment: Good point, I added that before I added accepts_nested_attributes to try and see if I could force creating the items manually.

Comment: Ok by adding optional: true and using the forms code, I now get this error: ArgumentError (When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.). Also when I log the params the entire hash is now marked permitted: false - that explains the error!

Comment: Ok, the update action now fires, log says Template Exists and the nested params are totally ignored. Only the parent is updated, no children are created.

Comment: okay now you are on the right track. This now happens because in create you never create associations. So there is nothing to update. update only works when there is an ID coming in for association. if you are going to create an association from update, you need to first build them in edit action. Or iterate on your new associations in update and before you update template , in a each loop use `@template.build_template_item(Item)`

Comment: I think I can form an answer now. Give me a few. I don't have active dev env right now, so had to get info from comments :D

Comment: Thanks, so I have a catch-22 as there is no edit action. It's an api. The template already exists and in this update I need to add new children to it. Hence why there are no ids in the json. Hmmm...so I guess I will have to build the children in the template update action (maybe by calling a build_children method on the template model).

Comment: Yep you need to build associations in update by looping on them, check my updated comment. I am posting an answer shortly.

Comment: @rmcsharry, have you tried wrapping the nested association's attributes in the controller?

Comment: Dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574595/rails-4-not-updating-nested-attributes-via-json/27609764?

Comment: @kmanzana Indeed this appears to be a duplicate and I have implemented the monkey_patch provided by lakesare in his answer to that question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Rails 4 Not Updating Nested Attributes Via JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574595/rails-4-not-updating-nested-attributes-via-json)

Comment: @kmanzana It turns out the Rails nested attributes is only one half of the problem.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you forget that params.require(:template).permit( ... is a method that is returning a value and when you call params to modify it later you are only modifying params that have not been permitted yet. what you want to do is swap the order of when you are performing the parameter manipulation.

```
def template_params
  params[:template][:template_items_attributes] = params[:template_items_attributes]
  params.require(:template).permit(:id, :account_id, :name, :title, :info, template_items_attributes: [:id, :is_completed, :content, :item_type])
end
```

UPDATE: wrap_parameters was the culprit as it was not including nested parameters in the wrapped params. this fixes the issue

UPDATE: this answer implements a different solution
[Rails 4 Not Updating Nested Attributes Via JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19574595/rails-4-not-updating-nested-attributes-via-json)

This is a long open request in github!! crazy 
https://github.com/rails/rails/pull/19254

UPDATE: this was finally merged in AR 6
https://github.com/rails/rails/commit/62b7ad46c0f3ff24980956daadba46ccb2568445

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, they are still marked as permitted: false.

Comment: Looking at this again, this SHOULD be the correct answer. Why the hell is Rails marking the params as false after doing this?

Comment: are all parameters marked as false? including the template parameters? then it is probably because everything needs to go inside template:

Comment: I have made a change to my answer to take that into account.

Comment: Thanks. The template_items_attributes are removed when I examine template_params in the update action. I am rapidly concluding this is not possible in Rails and that the request must ensure the parameter containing the children ends with "_attributes" before hitting the controller.

Comment: So I just tested that idea. I put the template_params method back to how it was at the very start. Sent a request from client with the child already called "template_items_attributes" in the params, and in the update action it is no longer there! Rails is removing the entire array...maybe because there are no ids?

Comment: Can you share a params dump before templates_params and the result of templates_params?

Comment: Oh... I just realized that you are using delete. This returns a key pair object I will update my example to correct this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157165/discussion-between-carlos-roque-and-rmcsharry).

Answer (score 1):

**Problem**
Your problem is in your `update` action you are trying to save the associations on `@template` that have not been built yet. Because there are no 'ids' coming in with the hash, the update function just ignores them.

**The Solution**
Is to iterate on the array of association hashes coming in through to the `update` action, and build them on the `@template` before calling `update` on the `@template`.

Here's the sudo code (haven't tried it, so don't copy paste) :

**models**

```
class Template < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  has_many :template_items
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :template_items, allow_destroy: true
end


class TemplateItem < ApplicationRecord  
  belongs_to :template, optional:true  # <------ CHANGE
  validates_presence_of :template

  enum item_type: {item: 0, heading: 1} 
end
```

**Strong params definition**

```
params.require(:template).permit(
      :id, :account_id, :name, :title, :info, 
      template_items_attributes: [:id, :is_completed, :content, :item_type]
  )
```

**Update Action**

```
def update

    template_params.template_items.each do |item_hash| # <------ CHANGE
        @template.template_items.build(item_hash)
    end

    if @template.update(template_params)
      render json: @template
    else
      render json: ErrorSerializer.serialize(@template.errors), status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
 end
```

Comment: Thanks. I will try your code but it won't work because the fundamental problem is that accepts_nested_attributes_for adds an "attribute_writer" which requires that the params for children ends with the word "_attributes". My request doesn't have that in the json. No matter how I try to add that to "tempalte_items" in the template_params method, Rails keeps throwing the child attributes away or always marks them false! :(

Comment: FYI the optional: true is only ensuring that 'Template must exist' before creating the children, so surely that's not the issue, since they will always exist in my scenario, which is updating an existing Template but at the same time creating new children.

Comment: Right, in your case you should not need `optional: true` because you always create the template first.

Comment: I totally understand what you are saying with this answer. So I tried your code now (with the changes).  template_params.template_items.each -> NoMethodError (undefined method `template_items' for #<ActionController::Parameters:0x007fc082fef1b0>).  I also tried renaming that parameter array like before to template_items_attributes, but it is always marked false or just removed by the permit code. So how can the update ever work? It never gets the children.

Comment: eg. in the update, when I try this: template_params[:template_items_attributes].each it throws Forbidden Attributes error.

Comment: Here is the really weird thing: if I just do params.permit! then your update code works and builds the children fine. Something is very weird about strong params in this situation of adding new children to an existing parent. Yet the article you linked to is EXACTLY this scenario and he never mentions having to build the children in the update action.

Comment: Right. That strong param definition should work. And yet I have experienced  wonkiness before with naming conventions when you have a model with two words. I would check all the singular/plural conventions when referring to template_items model. There could be a bug there is why they are not getting white listed properly.

Comment: You just read my mind - I am in the process of renaming the model to 'items' and see what happens.

Comment: Ok, same result. Conclusion: this is only supported when creating a parent - then it will auto-create new children. If you are updating a parent, you cannot use this technique to simultaneously create new children. The article you linked is the former and I am trying to do the latter.

Comment: Although that article says "accepts_nested_attributes_for is an ActiveRecord directive that allows one model to create or update instances of other related models" - could be wrong I suppose.

Answer (score -1):

```
 def  template_params 
    template_params = params.require(:template).permit(:id, :account_id, :name,:title, :info, template_items: [:id, :is_completed, :content, :item_type])
    template_params[:template_items_attributes] = template_params.delete :template_items      
    template_params.permit!
end
```

Comment: Posting code without an explanation is not very helpful. Also, this does not work because  they need to be 'template_items_attributes' to even reach this part of the code -> so you cannot see 'template_items' inside the method, Rails has already removed them.